# API response from inomnia is different than the error (from yup validator) on client side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, yup

So I am using yup validator

```
beeraverage: yup.number("Not a number").min(0).nullable(true),
```

testing with `"beeraverage": "4.5.9",` in the object. Then I get this with insomnia:

[image]

As expected.

Using this code to catch up the yup error:

```
.catch(yupError => {
            const errors = yupError.inner.reduce((acc, error) => {
                const { path, message } = error;
                if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(path)) {
                    acc[path] = [message];
                }
                else {
                    acc[path].push(message);
                }
                return acc;
            }, {});

            res.status(errorCode).json(new InvalidFieldErrorResponse(
                'Data invalid',
                errors,
                errorCode
            ));
        });
```

(Btw how can I get the error "Not a number" written in the code above in the validator ???)

and then when I try in the client side using axios :

```
axios.put('http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/bar/' + id, changes, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` } })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("reponse update bar: " + JSON.stringify(response.data.result, null, 4));
                setResponse(response.data.result);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("error update bar: " + JSON.stringify(error, null, 4));
                setError(error.message);
            })
            .finally(function () {
                setLoading(false);
            });
```

I get an error completely different and nothing to do with it :
[image]

How can I get the errors from yup in the client side please ?

Answer (score 0):

So because axios encapsulate it, the error call that you get in insomnia/postman is:

> error.response.data

and map on `error.response.data.fieldErrors`

And for the custom error message:

```
beeraverage: yup.number().typeError("Not a number").min(0).nullable(true),
```

and to get the fields errors:

```
axios.put('http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/bar/' + id, changes, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` } })
            .then(function (response) {
                //console.log("reponse update : " + JSON.stringify(response.data.result, null, 4));
                setResponse(response.data.result);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                var errors = "";
                for (const fields in error.response.data.fieldErrors) {
                    console.log("fields: " + JSON.stringify(fields, null, 4))
                    error.response.data.fieldErrors[fields].map(item => (
                        errors = errors.concat("\n" + item)
                    ))
                }
                setError(errors);
            })
            .finally(function () {
                setLoading(false);
            });
```